# Proving that having a unique embedding implies purely inseparable.

Tags: extension-field

In the problem statement, we are given $k \subset K$ an algebraic field extension of characteristic p > 0, L an algebraically closed field containing K, and $\delta: k \rightarrow L$ be an embedding. What I'm trying to show is that if there exists exactly one embedding $\tau: K \rightarrow L$ extending $\delta$ that $k \subset K$ is purely inseparable.

I've shown this when $k \subset K$ is finite, and now I'm trying to prove that I can reduce to this case.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the extension is separable, you can take a suitable polynomial, permute its roots and be done.

Comment: But how do I know that it's separable?

Comment: My point is that if there is a separable element, you can obtain an nontrivial embedding.